# Ansible. Fast way to check syntax?

Tags: ansible

Is there a way to check playbook syntax and variables?

I'm trying to dry-run(--check) but for some reasons it works really slow. It looks like it tries to perform an action instead of just check the syntax

I want to omit en errors like this:

```
..."msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: ERROR! 'application_name' is undefined"}
```

Answer (score 83, accepted):

This is expected behaviour according to the documentation:

> When ansible-playbook is executed with --check it will not make any
> changes on remote systems. Instead, any module instrumented to support
> ‘check mode’ (which contains most of the primary core modules, but it
> is not required that all modules do this) will report what changes
> they would have made rather than making them. Other modules that do
> not support check mode will also take no action, but just will not
> report what changes they might have made.

Old link (does not work anymore): http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_checkmode.html

New link: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_checkmode.html#using-check-mode

If you would like to check the YAML syntax you can use syntax-check.

```
ansible-playbook rds_prod.yml  --syntax-check
playbook: rds_prod.yml
```

Comment: So, there is no way to fastcheck that all variables are declared? it's pity  to find that you mistyped some name in the end of the long playbook

Comment: There are two types of checks: syntax-check and dry-run, I am not aware of other type of check as of now.

Comment: Be careful with `--check`. Since Ansible 2.2 you can force a task to run in normal mode and make changes to the system, even when the playbook is called with `--check`. Read this: [Enabling or disabling check mode for tasks](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_checkmode.html#enabling-or-disabling-check-mode-for-tasks)

Comment: You have to force tasks in check mode if you need their results (e.g. listing files, mountpoints, etc.). This should be done only for tasks without side-effect.

Comment: The link defined in the post is not working anymore. Please update the link.

Answer (score 7):

I was looking for the same, but was not satisfied by the `--syntax-check` option, since it does not work its way down to the roles. A more complete check can be performed with [ansible-lint](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-lint/) which also includes style-checks. But if you turn off all style-checks, then you have a pretty complete syntax-check.

So do something like

```
ansible-lint -x $(echo $(ansible-lint -L | awk -F':' '{print $1}' | grep '^[^ ]') | tr ' ' ',') my_playbook.yml
```

Comment: Be aware this does not spot syntax errors in task command arguments. (I had `yum_repository: des**t**cription: ...` which wasn't discovered).

Comment: You can use `--syntax-check` on an individual role using something like: `ansible localhost -m include_role -a name=role_to_check --syntax-check`

Comment: @JiříBaum just tried that and it didn't work, it executes the role :-(

Comment: Seems as if the `ansible-lint -L` output no more uses colons after the keyword, so removing the `-F':'` should help to get it working again.

Answer (score 0):

Add a task to fail the playbook when variables aren't defined. This should be the first task run.

Another option is to ensure that all variables have a default value in the /defaults/ directory so that it never fails, but the variables can still be overwritten at other levels.

Answer (score 0):

My preferd way is

```
pip install yamllint
yamllint -d "{extends: default, rules: {quoted-strings: enable}}" .
```

Since I really want to catch quote errors, e.g.

```
validate: bash -c ' ' \""
```

This is valid yaml, since yaml will just quote the string and turn it into:

```
   validate: "bash -c ' ' \\\"\""
```

Whilst there was just clearly a quote missing at the beginning of the validate comand.

So a normal yaml checker will not detect this, yamllint wil not even detect this in it's default configuration, so turn on quoted-strings checker.